# writing test for rubyonrails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-2

I am new to writing test for rubyonrails app like rspect, steak, cucumber etc. How do I start or learn so that it will help me to write beautiful codes?

You can give some simple example or some url where I can understand from zero.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber - a good podcast for beginner

[The RSpec Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356379) - also very useful

It's a good point to start and then Google help you

Answer (score 1):

1) Start by reading the [rails testing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) just to get a feel for testing.

2) Become familiar with the various [testing frameworks](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/testing_frameworks.html) (Cucumber, rspec, testunit, steak, minitest), watch screencasts ([railscasts](http://railscasts.com/?search=testing&tag_id=7&utf8=%E2%9C%93), [TeachMeToCode](http://teachmetocode.com/screencasts/)) and then try and choose one that appeals to you.

3) Write tests!! and get help as you need it from StackOverflow. If you like RSpec then the [RSpec book](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book) is very helpful, but not essential.

My personal opinion on frameworks:
I started out really liking cucumber but I eventually found it very verbose and I didn't like using it for my integration tests and then RSpec for my unit and functional tests. I now like using just RSpec with Capybara and Shoulda matchers. TestUnit can be even less verbose than RSpec but personally I find RSpec to be the happy medium between writing self documenting code and not being overly verbose.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started with RSpec a few days ago and it was pretty hard (it still is actually). You could start from railstutorial.org. The author follows the TDD principle. More info available at [RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) and [Cucumber](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber) github page. Be sure to check out the wiki.